# Check if an URL is a valid Google search URL

Tags: regex, validation, url

I'd like to check if an URL is a valid Google search URL

(e.g. http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=car&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=8f6073eaa2ffaabc&biw=1280&bih=868 is a valid URL for a Google search for the word "car" whereas http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&sourciw=1280&bih=868&fp=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&cad=b isn't [it displays a blank page])

Does someone know of a way to do this ? (regex, validator, ...)

Comment: You probably just need to check whether there is a *q* parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for the presence of the `q` parameter:

```
/[?&]q=[^&]+/
```

Wrap in parenthesis if you need to extract the search term:

```
/[?&]q=([^&]+)/
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/Mprs0a8wLb)

---

**EDIT**
Actually, the correct regex is this, since the "query string" is in the hash of the URL:

```
/[#&]q=([^&]+)/
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/yUk3IHtQN9)

Comment: @Bruno NP. Really just typed out what Gumbo suggested.

Comment: Also, you can test Regular expressions in different programming languages [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/).

Comment: Can this Ruby regular expression be converted to JavaScript regular expression somehow?

Comment: @AndersonGreen `/[#&]q=([^&]+)/` _is_ a valid JavaScript RegExp :)